# For each array item with key collect value and make new array with key and array of values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've got an array with structure like

```
   linkword =  ['people','http:mysite.org/people-appears-here'],
    ['people','http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-to'],
    ['people','http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-aswell'],
    ['crayons','http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here-to'],
    ['crayons','http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here-aswell'],
    ['boats','http:mysite.org/boats-appears-here-aswell'],
```

And I want to create an array (hash?) like

```
['people' => ['http:mysite.org/people-appears-here', 'http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-to', 'http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-aswell']], 
['crayons' => ['http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here', 'http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here-to']], 
['boats' => ['http:mysite.org/boats-appears-here']],
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do above

```
linkword.each_with_object(a) { |(k,v),m| 
    while a == k 
    temphash[a] << v
    end
    pp temphash
    }
    end
```

Comment: What does adsfdsf mean? Your code is not valid Ruby. What is your question?

Comment: You recently asked if you should use a framework in your PHP website, and then deleted the question when it began attracting down votes and close votes. This is rather a subjective question, and so isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow - when you get a moment, have a look at the help pages. You could look into a lightweight or component framework, and add new framework features as time allows - see Slim, Symfony, Zend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
linkword.group_by(&:first).each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), h| h[k] = v.flatten.reject{|i| i == k } }
#=> {"people"=>["http:mysite.org/people-appears-here", "http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-to", "http:mysite.org/people-appears-here-aswell"],
#    "crayons"=>["http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here-to", "http:mysite.org/crayons-appears-here-aswell"],
#    "boats"=>["http:mysite.org/boats-appears-here-aswell"]}
```